# What is the beans: tag in the Spring template app?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I just created a Spring template app using the Spring Source IDE, and it defined the ViewResolver like this in servlet-context.xml:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

I'm unfamiliar with this configuration, and I usually see the ViewResolver defined this way:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent actually. In the first case, `beans` is the namespace prefix for the Spring beans [XML schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd). The mapping of namespace prefix to namespace in schema definition is done elsewhere--most likely in the root element.

In the second case, no prefix is necessary because the *default* namespace is mapped to the same schema--again, most likely in the root element. From the documentation:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

The `xmlns:` means the default namespace is *http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans*. In the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, you see the namespace is mapped to the Spring beans schema where that namespace is defined:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
```

So it is actually just an XML thing rather than a Spring thing.